# Is it possible to install Firefox 3.0 as well as the default package?

Tags: 10.10, firefox, apt

I'm a webdeveloper and using ubuntu 10.10 maverick. I want to track down a bug that appears in firefox 3.0, but not 3.5/3.6. Is there an easy way to install firefox 3.0 without it overwriting/clobbering my main install of firefox? i.e. I want to install both 3.0 and 3.6 at the same time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download old firefox version here:

ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

You can extract it to some dir in your home and run it from there. Please be careful to use a new profile.

You can use:

```
./firefox -P profilename
```

or

```
./firefox -P ProfileManager
```

to select witch profile you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps too late, but...get my [FoxTester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/141505/) extension. It allows you to install any number of Firefox versions you want and launch them without even leaving your default Firefox. Each version gets it's own profile, so you can mess things without fear. Everything is done through the extension context menu and the extension detects Firefox installation files from a monitored folder. All you need is to download the versions you want to the same folder and install via FoxTester. It also allows to check hash number of downloaded files.

See demo at http://foxtester-extension.blogspot.com/